# why is it called munitraya sampradayam? Who are the three munis?

Tags: vishnu

What is the munitrayasampradayam of vadakalai in Srivaishnava sampradayam? who are the three munis in this sampradayam

Comment: I believe it's not about sri vaishnavas its madvas 1. Madvacharya 2.Jayatheertha 3. Vyasa Raja